# wait to complete all ajax function called inside for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop

I have a function reboot() which is expected to call after all the ajax call complete which is in for loop.

I have tried to call "reboot" function after all "proceedSaving" complete which is inside forloop. array value may be change as `[1,3], [1,4,5] , [3,4],[2,2,5]`

```
saveSettings{
      for (i in [1,2,5,4]) {
        proceedSaving(i,param1,param2);
      }
      reboot(); //
}

async proceedSaving(i,param1,param2)){
..
 let url = '/ajax/test.php?command=updateUsbPortConfig';
           await performAjaxPostRequest(url, urlParams, saveResponseHandler);
            
}           

function saveResponseHandler(readyState, responseText, responseXml, status){
    if ((readyState == 4) && ((status == 200) || (status == 0))) {
        var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
        
        if (response.status === 'success') {
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: make `saveSettings` an `async` function, and `await proceedSaving()`.

Comment: tried by not working

Comment: Does `performAjaxPostRequest` return a promise that resolves when the response is back? I guess not. `await` is not useful if you don't give it a promise.

Comment: no it won't return promise performAjaxPostRequest

Comment: So, then your `await` for it is useless.

Comment: Why not using `Promise.all`?This would ensure that the `reboot()` function is called only after all the promises from the `proceedSaving` calls have been resolved. If you want I can share this approach.

Comment: can I use promise all for "for loop"

Comment: @user3386779, I added the answer. You can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use [***`Promise.all`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which ensures that the `reboot()` function is called only after all the promises from the `proceedSaving` calls have been resolved. Something like:

```js
async function saveSettings() {
  const promises = [];

  for (let i of [1, 2, 5, 4]) {
    promises.push(proceedSaving(i, param1, param2));
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
  reboot();
}
// ...Rest of your code
```

**NOTE:**

`Promise.all()` returns a fulfilled promise when all promises are **resolved**. You mentioned ***complete*** in your question. So if by *complete* you mean settled(either resolved or rejected) then you can also take a look ***[`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)***.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: reboot will call rebofore calling saveResponseHandler

Comment: @user3386779 I didn't get you correctly. From the snippet you provided I just provided the answer to it. There is no call to `saveResponseHandler`. But if you need to call it. You can call it after `reboot`. Correct me if I understood you wrongly

Answer (score 2):

`await` will only be useful if you pass it a promise that resolves when the response is back, but apparently your `performAjaxPostRequest` does not return such a promise.

There are APIs that return promises, but if you want to use your `performAjaxPostRequest` function, then promisify it.

Once you have done that, also make `saveSettings` an async function, and await the promise you get in the loop.

Here is how it could look:

```
// Make this function async
async function saveSettings() {
    for (i in [1,2,5,4]) {
        // Await the returned promise
        await proceedSaving(i, param1, param2);
    }
    reboot();
}

// Promisify performAjaxPostRequest -- note that it doesn't take the third argument
function promisePostResponse(url, urlParams) {
    return new Promise(resolve => 
        performAjaxPostRequest(url, urlParams, (...args) => resolve(args))
    );
}

async proceedSaving(i, param1, param2) {
    // ...
    const url = '/ajax/test.php?command=updateUsbPortConfig';
    // Call the promisified function, and await its promise
    const [readyState, responseText, responseXml, status] = await promisePostResponse(url, urlParams);
    // Now call the response handler (or do the job here inplace)
    saveResponseHandler(readyState, responseText, responseXml, status);
}
```

If you prefer that `saveSettings` performs the requests without waiting for each individual one before continuing with the next, then change it to:

```
async function saveSettings() {
    await Promise.all([1,2,5,4].map(i => {
        proceedSaving(i, param1, param2);
    });
    reboot();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using Promise.all to wait all async function completed

```js
async saveSettings {
    const Allfechs = [1, 2, 5, 4].map(i=>proceedSaving(i, param1,param2))
await Promise.all(Allfechs)
  reboot(); //
}

async proceedSaving(i, param1, param2)) {
  ..
  let url = '/ajax/test.php?command=updateUsbPortConfig';
  await performAjaxPostRequest(url, urlParams, saveResponseHandler);

}

function saveResponseHandler(readyState, responseText, responseXml, status) {
  if ((readyState == 4) && ((status == 200) || (status == 0))) {
    var response = JSON.parse(responseText);

    if (response.status === 'success') {

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry tried adding await after for .but troughing error

Comment: yes,its my mistake,  I change the answer again